# mp4 video recorded from iPhone 8 not playing iPad mini 2 & website

Tags: objective-c, h.264, hevc

I am capturing video using UIImagePickerController. Exporting video into mp4. Code is here:

```
- (NSString *)convertMOVToMp4:(NSURL *)url : (NSString *)filename
   {
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory

      NSString *dataPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/doctorphoto"];
      NSError *error = nil;
      if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

      NSString *videoPath1 = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xyz2.mov"]; //Add the file name
      NSString *movfilepath = videoPath1;
      NSURL *videoURL = url;
      NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
      [videoData writeToFile:videoPath1 atomically:NO];

      AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movfilepath] options:nil];
      NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];

      if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality])
       {
         AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
         videoPath1 = [self getLocalVideoPath:filename];
         exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath1];
         NSLog(@"videopath of your mp4 file = %@",videoPath1);  // PATH OF YOUR .mp4 FILE
         exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;

        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            switch ([exportSession status]) {

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                    NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
                    break;

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"Export success.");
                    [self.delegate onCompleteConvert: videoPath1 : anyobj];
                    break;
                }
                NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                [fileManager removeItemAtPath:movfilepath error:NULL];
            }];
        }

        return videoPath1;
    }
```

Its converting into mp4. Then uploading into AWS server. This link is streaming into iPhone 8, but not playing in iPhone 5S, iPad mini2. In website, audio is playing, but showing black screen.If I follow the same procedure from iPhone 5S or iPad mini, its working fine. Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, but is the captured file encoded with hevc?

Comment: A poor presentation of code...

Comment: Sorry EI Tomato, I am new here, so don't know the right pattern. Sorry for that.

Comment: @szatmary, when i am checking file in my mac, its showing h264

Comment: Thank you everyone for spending your time. I have fixed it by changing preset AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080 instead of AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough. Also added exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;. Now its working. If you have better solution, please let me know. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This change solved the problem:

```
- (NSString *)convertMOVToMp4:(NSURL *)url : (NSString *)filename
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory

    NSString *dataPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/doctorphoto"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

    NSString *videoPath1 = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xyz2.mov"]; //Add the file name
    NSString *movfilepath = videoPath1;
    NSURL *videoURL = url;
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    [videoData writeToFile:videoPath1 atomically:NO];

    AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movfilepath] options:nil];
    NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];

    if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality])
    {
        NSString *preset = AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080;

        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName:preset];
        videoPath1 = [self getLocalVideoPath:filename];
//        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//        videoPath1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/doctorphoto/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0], filename];
        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath1];
        NSLog(@"videopath of your mp4 file = %@",videoPath1);  // PATH OF YOUR .mp4 FILE
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;
        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            switch ([exportSession status]) {

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                    NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
                    break;

                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"Export success.");
                    [self.delegate onCompleteConvert: videoPath1 : anyobj];
                    break;
            }
//            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath1, self, nil, nil);
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:movfilepath error:NULL];
        }];
    }

    return videoPath1;
}
```